# Finding the expectation value of the annihilation operator with respect to a given state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators

Using dirac notation we were given a state vector 
$$|\Psi(t=0)\rangle = A\sum\limits_{q=0}^Q \frac{1}{(q+i)} |\phi_q\rangle$$ Where $\phi$ is part of a complete orthonormal set. I found the normalization constant to be 
$$A = \sum\limits_{q=0}^Q\sqrt{q^2+1}$$
Such that the inner product $\langle\Psi(t=0)|\Psi(t=0)\rangle = 1$

When I attempted to find the expectation value i ended up with 
$$\langle \hat{a} \rangle = \sum\limits_{k=0}^Q\sum\limits_{q=0}^Q\frac{A_k}{k-i}\frac{A_q}{q+i}\sqrt{q}\delta_{k,q-1}$$

Setting $k=q-1$ I then obtained 
$$\langle\hat{a}\rangle=\sum\limits_{q=0}^Q \frac{A_{k}A_{q}\sqrt{q}}{q^2-q+1-i}$$

After expanding this I get 
$$\langle\hat{a}\rangle=\sum\limits_{q=0}^Q\frac{q^2-q+1+i}{q^2-q+1-i}\sqrt{q}$$

This answer however does not look correct to me and I'm not quite sure where I went wrong or how to 'troubleshoot' my problem. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Not looking for someone to find the actual answer but more for someone to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that Physics.StackExchange is *not* a homework help site. Please [see this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093)